# How Can I HIDE the high score information contained inside a URL?

Tags: php, mysql

The code I have creates a simple high score table by taking the name and score of a player from the URL. Example: http://www.example.com/hs/test2.php?n=Jimmy&s=15000

In the example above, the player name is Jimmy and his score was 15000.

The database is MySQL.

I don't want players to be able to see this information in the URL. How can I hide it or protect it somehow? The PHP code I'm using is below:

```
/*test1.php*/

<?
echo "<h5>High Scores</h5>";
$con = mysql_connect("fdb3.runhosting.com","databse","password");
if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highscores  ORDER BY Score  DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['Name'] . " | " . $row['Score'];
 echo "<h5> </h5>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

/*test2.php*/
<?php

 $nam = $_GET["n"];
 $sco = $_GET["s"];

 $con = mysql_connect("fdb3.runhosting.com","database","password");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 mysql_select_db("database", $con);
 $result = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO highscores (Name, Score)
 VALUES ( '" . $nam . "', '" . $sco . "' ) " );

 mysql_close($con);
 header( 'Location: http://yoursubdomain/1st_textdocument.php' ) ;
 ?>
```

I think there might be a way to use the POST command, but I haven't been able to make it work. Anyone know how to improve this code so it doesn't show the information being past by the URL to the PHP? Thank you for any assistance! :)

Comment: If you don't want it in the URL, then don't put it in the URL. Even if you switch to `POST` instead of `GET`, the information can still be viewed by anyone looking for it. Use a less revealing ID instead (then get the score from a database), or encrypt it. Also, stop using the mysql extension as it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` instead of `GET`, you need to change the method in your HTML form and use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Technically answers the question ... but : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: Anyway it's possible to send and modify datas, you don't even need an addon, the fact is that he should protect his page with a one-use token given after the end of a game

Comment: True - but that FF plug-in just happens to be what I use when attempting to break my own forms. Just using it as an illustration as to how easy it is to tamper with POST data.

Comment: I am just looking for a simple solution to fix this problem. I don't know how to encrypt the URL or hide the URL from players. If you can show some code on how to do these sorts of things it would be a big help.

Comment: Do you have a HTML form?

Comment: The only code I have that is working is posted above in PHP. It creates a simple high score table and then populates it with a record by receiving information passed to it from a URL. That is all I have so far. No HTML form.